# Undefined externals when linking DLL to Visual C++

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012

I've got a dll from a vendor I want to use in a C++ Visual Studio 2012 project.  It comes with a `.lib` file.

When linking I get:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList referenced in function "int __cdecl Ftexam(void)" (?Ftexam@@YAHXZ) C:\Users\Terry\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project1\Win32Project1\ftexam.obj ftexample
```

I've read similar posts but I'm not getting anywhere.  I think I'm doing everything according to those answers, but I still get a undefined reference error when linking.

1. I've added the dll.lib file to the /Linker/Addional Dependencies list.
2. I've made sure the dll.h file is included in my source
3. I've put the `dll.lib` file with in my project directory and made sure that if I remove it from there,I get `cannot find dll.lib` when linking (i.e., it is "in the build")

In my supplied `dll.h` header file I have this:

```
#ifdef DLL_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
.
.
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef ULONG   FT_STATUS;
.
.
DLL_API FT_STATUS FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(
    LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs
);
```

and my calling code is:

```
#include dll.h

int Ftexam(){
    FT_STATUS ftStatus=0; 
    DWORD numDevs = 0;

    // create the device information list 
    ftStatus = FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(&numDevs); 
}
```

I realize there is probably some name mangling going on so I looked at the DLL symbols using depends. It lists these exports with the "Undecorate C++ functions" option disabled, (so, these are the unmangled  exports):

```
FT_Open
FT_Close
FT_Read
....
FT_CyclePort
FT_CreateDeviceInfoList<  <<<<<this reference!!!!
FT_GetDeviceInfoList
```

The identified export above obviously does not match `__imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList`

Is there a tool around that can look at the definitions in a .lib file, or some way for visual studio to display that?

UPDATE:

With the use of dumpbin I was able to see the symbol in the .lib was

```
__imp_FT_CreateDeviceInfoList 

instead of 

__imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList
```

this I tracked to the .lib for the 64 bit version of the DLL instead of the 32 bit version. (One of the combinations I tried to solve this in the first place).

To simplify the post, I had indicated that the header contained:

```
DLL_API FT_STATUS FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs);

When in fact, it actually contains:

DLL_API FT_STATUS WINAPI FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs);
```

because WINAPI was #defined

so changing

```
#define WINAPI
to
#define WINAPI __stdcall
```

along with having the correct .lib fixed the issue.

Comment: WINAPI should have been already defined correctly by Windows.  I recognize the library you are using and currently use it myself without modification.  Did you "#include <windows.h>" before including the library header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FT_CreateDeviceInfoList()` is not declaring any calling convention in the .h file, so it uses whatever the compiler's default calling convention is.  Your compiler is defaulting to `__cdecl`, which is normal behavior for most C++ compilers.  Chances are that the compiler that created the DLL is actually using a different default calling convention instead.  Try editing the .h file to specify `__stdcall`, for example, and see if it makes any difference, eg:

```
DLL_API FT_STATUS __stdcall FT_CreateDeviceInfoList(LPDWORD lpdwNumDevs);
```

Most DLL vendors use `__stdcall` for compatibility with the widest selection of compilers, not just C/C++ compilers, though some vendors do use `__cdecl` or even `__fastcall` (which is implemented differently by different compiler vendors, so watch out with that one).

Worse case scenario, you can use a disassembler, like IDA or WinDASM, or just use your IDE's own debugger, to look at the actual assembly code for `FT_CreateDeviceInfoList()` inside the DLL and see how it is managing the call stack when accessing the `lpdwNumDevs` parameter and returning the `FT_STATUS` value.  That will tell you exactly which calling convention it is actually using.

**UPDATE**: doing some online searches, I see many examples of .NET code that call `FT_CreateDeviceInfoList()` with the `__stdcall` calling convention applied to its declaration, so that is a good place to start.  If that works, then you should contact the DLL vendor and ask them to fix their .h file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  By using dumpbin I could see that the symbol in the .lib was __imp_FT_CreateDeviceInfoList vs __imp__FT_CreateDeviceInfoList.  I tracked this down to referencing a 64 bit version of the .lib instead of the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Visual Studio command prompt. Fire the following command to list the symbols in the lib file:

> dumpbin /all dll.lib

Redirect the above to a text file, as the output scrolls off quickly

Answer (score -1):

What you're doing should work as far as I can see. But you can always just forget about the .lib file and use the DLL directly, loading it with LoadLibrary and getting the addresses of the functions you want to use with GetProcAddress.